# How to do dataframe for a lot of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a data frame with columns regarding sales. There's a column called "UnitPrice", that has the price of each product, A column called "Category", that has a key number of each product, a column called " Product Standard Cost" And lastly there is a column called " Sales Amount".

I want to do a table regarding the revenues of each category. So the (Unit Price - ProductStandardCost) x Sales Amount for each category

I have tried but i cant do all the functions in the same line.

Comment: Please share a few rows of sample input and the desired output. `dput()` is a nice function for generating sample data, you can use `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` to make a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows of your data. Choose a suitable subset to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Something like the following based on what you are saying: ```data %>% mutate(calculation = (`Unit Price` - ProductStandardCost) * `Sales Amount`)```. And if you want to do this based on each category, you can just use `groupby(Category)`, and run the calculation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.